# Use of unresolved identifier 'Braintree'

Tags: iphone, swift, braintree

I am using the braintree using the cocoapods in my swift ios application. I successfully installed the braintree in my ios app. my pod file structure is:

```
target 'appName' do
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
#  use_frameworks!

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6.0'
pod 'CardIO'
pod 'NSURL+QueryDictionary', '~> 1.0'
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'FLEX'
pod 'InAppSettingsKit'
pod 'iOS-Slide-Menu'

#  pod "BraintreeDropIn", :path => "./"

#  pod 'Braintree/Apple-Pay'
pod 'Braintree/PayPal'
#  pod 'Braintree/Venmo'

end
```

I added below header file in bridge file:

```
#import "BraintreeCore.h"
#import "BraintreePayPal.h"
#import "Braintree.h"
```

Now when I try to use in my code it says 
`Braintree.setReturnURLScheme("com.your-company.Your-App.payments")`

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Braintree'

So please suggest.

Comment: product->clean and build xcode again

Comment: try `@import Braintree;` in bridge file

Comment: Try **BTAppSwitch.setReturnURLScheme()**

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `import` anything in bridging header file. After the installation from `cocoapods`, you can `import` it in any `swift` file as below,

```
import Braintree
```

And to set `returnUrlScheme`, you can use `BTAppSwitch` as below

```
BTAppSwitch.setReturnURLScheme("com.your-company.Your-App.payments")
```

Comment: it's saying "No such module 'Braintree'"

Comment: @MiteshKhatri are you sure your project compiles without any issue if you don' import `Braintree`. Importing files in Bridging headers is required when you add an `objC` files explicitly in your code but with cocoapods it is not required.

Comment: Yes, it compiles without any error if I do not included Braintree.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I get `Use of undeclared identifier 'BTAppSwitch'`